# I am working on lightning:recordEditForm. Can we use it on record page of another object than mentioned in objectApi Name

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-apps

I have created below lightning:recordEditForm in aura components to create Contact and placed it on record page of account so that contact can pick accountId of loaded account record. But Lightning:inputFields are not getting displayed in the form.
If I place same component on record page of Contacts, it's working fine.

Code->
Component :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="flag" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="confirmationMsg" type="boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.flag}">
    <div style="width:500px;border:1px solid black;">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="rec" recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Contact" onsubmit="{!c.onSubmitAction}" onsuccess="{!c.onSuccessAction}">
            <lightning:card title="Create Related Contact" iconName="utility:add">
                <div style="padding:20px;">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" /> 
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
                </div>
                <aura:set attribute="actions">
                    <lightning:button label="Save" type="submit" />
                </aura:set>
            </lightning:card>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.confirmationMsg}">
    <ui:message title="Confirmation" severity="confirm" closable="true">
        Contact has been created successfully.
    </ui:message>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Javascript Controller :

```
    ({
onSubmitAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var accId = component.find("rec").get("v.recordId");
    event.preventDefault(); //it just stops the standard submit
    var evtFields = event.getParam("fields"); //list of all the fields of that objectApiName
    evtFields["AccountId"] = accId;
    component.find("rec").submit(evtFields);
},
onSuccessAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Contact has been created successfully");
    component.set("v.flag",false); //hide the edit form
    component.set("v.flag",true); //creates a new form
    var param = event.getParams();
    var recId = param.response.id; //this will return the record Id after success.
    console.log(recId);
    if(recId != ''){
        component.set("v.confirmationMsg",true);
    }
}
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that the record id that is loaded alongside the form does not correspond to a contact id, but an account. So, it is expected that your fields do not display. for it to load, you either need to have an empty id or a contact id.

Comment: Thanks, I got my code corrected. Now, I have removed recordId="{!v.recordId}" from lightning:recordEditForm but, rather retrieved current account record Id in a separate attribute like below and then fetched that attribute in client side controller.

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />